# Remainder of DIV is not in EDX

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have defined `num1`, `num2`, and `remainder` variables as *DWORD*. I get 2 numbers from the user which are `num1`, and `num2`.  I'm trying to divide `num1` by `num2`.  The numbers I'm using are num1=37 and num2=5

```
sub    edx,edx    ; Zero edx
mov    eax,num1
mov    ebx,num2
div    ebx
mov    remainder,edx
mov    edx, OFFSET remainder
call   WriteInt
```

For some reason this prints out 7, which is the quotient, not the remainder.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If that is Irvine32, then `WriteInt` requires the value you want to print to be in _EAX_. _EAX_ was set to the quotient when your DIV instruction was done. Remove `mov    remainder,edx`
 `mov    edx, OFFSET remainder` and then put in the instruction `mov eax, edx` . That would move the remainder into _EAX_ and WriteInt should print that.

Comment: This is why we use debuggers to look at register values.  You would have seen that `edx` was right, and it was the printing code that had a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this.

```
mov    edx,0   ; Zero edx
mov    eax,num1
mov    ebx,num2
div    ebx      
mov    eax,edx     ; EAX = reminder
call   WriteDec    ; Display 2
```